# Monte Carlo Markov Chain

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-models, monte-carlo

I was trying to figure out what is a **Monte Carlo Markov Chain**. 
 From what I understand it is a way of computing an approximation of a probability distribution, which cannot compute exactly. 
So we keep sampling from a probability distribution, in order to be more accurate, reducing variance of the samples by increasing the number of examples, and this samples are given by Gibbs Sampling. 
This step-to-step process is a Markov Chain, but I don't really get the details of this one.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165/how-would-you-explain-markov-chain-monte-carlo-mcmc-to-a-layperson/12657#12657